# I am having an error when I interact with my smart contract

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask, revert-opcode

first of all here are the codes

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
var contractInstance;
var x = 0
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.ethereum.enable().then(function(accounts){
      contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(window.abi, "0xe6f4FDF7110B0412183F46896666CB55fab1d85A", {from: accounts[0]});
    });
    $("#get_data_button").click(fetchAndDisplay);
});
function fetchAndDisplay(){
  contractInstance.methods.betxc(x).send({value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether")}).then(function(res){
    if(res==0)
    console.log("you won!!!!!")
    else {
      console.log("you lost")
    }
  })
  };
```

here the smart contract code( I tried using remix to find the error but everything is fine there, I can perfectly interact with the contract.This makes me think that the error might be in the main.js file,the one above)

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
contract cointoss {
    event Won(string);
    event Def(string);
    uint monysent;
    uint tot;
    modifier costs(uint cost){
        require(msg.value >= cost);
        _;
    }
    string[] public data;
    function random() public view returns(uint){
        return block.timestamp % 2;
    }
    function  betxc(uint numb) payable public costs(0.01 ether) returns(uint){
        uint max= random();
        tot = tot + msg.value;
        if (max==numb){

            msg.sender.transfer(msg.value*2);
            tot -= msg.value*2;
            emit Won("somebody won");
        }
        emit Def("the contact interaction finished");
        return max;
 }
}
```

and here is the error that I ge in the error( I get an error in metamask too"ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code" and I can't send funds to the contract address directly, If this last information helps you)

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert","code":-32000,"data":{"0xccb22b990e1c56d2f45ad4ada4143c8ea721c924e875cd62601313d7402d3ea8":{"error":"revert","program_counter":46,"return":"0x"},"stack":"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganachYMHaCq/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/tmp/.mount_ganachYMHaCq/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)","name":"RuntimeError"}}}}'
Object { code: -32603, message: "Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"message\":\"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\",\"code\":-32000,\"data\":{\"0xccb22b990e1c56d2f45ad4ada4143c8ea721c924e875cd62601313d7402d3ea8\":{\"error\":\"revert\",\"program_counter\":46,\"return\":\"0x\"},\"stack\":\"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganachYMHaCq/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/tmp/.mount_ganachYMHaCq/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)\",\"name\":\"RuntimeError\"}}}}'" }
inpage.js:1:24326
Uncaught (in promise)
Object { code: -32603, message: "Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"message\":\"VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\",\"code\":-32000,\"data\":{\"0xccb22b990e1c56d2f45ad4ada4143c8ea721c924e875cd62601313d7402d3ea8\":{\"error\":\"revert\",\"program_counter\":46,\"return\":\"0x\"},\"stack\":\"RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganachYMHaCq/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\\n    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/tmp/.mount_ganachYMHaCq/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)\",\"name\":\"RuntimeError\"}}}}'" }
```

as you can see the contract is a simple coin toss contact, you can deduct that I am an absolute beginner in this area

Comment: This could be similar to a problem I am having: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102668/why-is-transaction-reverting-with-custom-smart-contract/102682#102682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same errors and I solved it now by raising the gas limit when sending transaction!

I recommend you raise your gas limit and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

ONe thing that maybe causing this issue

The front sends 1 ether

```
contractInstance.methods.betxc(x).send({value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether")})
```

and the contract when winning send twice that amount

```
msg.sender.transfer(msg.value*2);
```

For the transfer to succeed the contract needs to have a balance greater than 2 ether.

Note: `block.timestamp` isn't a good source of randomness.