# Why is transaction reverting with custom smart contract?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, revert-opcode, failed-transaction

I have [deployed a smart contract](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xd14bc40e232b90eaaf168c738ef06c9869c65986) to the Polygon Mumbai Testnet (it shouldn't really matter where I deployed it).

When sending a transaction to call a function on this contract, the transaction fails, and after looking through the instructions trace, it seems a REVERT opcode [was triggered](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0xdcccbae489c2e6f81c532bf549a6c376402c12ec4aa7f4e3b2d5eb77dc430dac).

There are no requires, asserts or anything in my code that would make me believe that a revert opcode would occur.

The only possibility I could think of is some error such as running out of stack space (if that's even a thing), although I would have presumed any such errors would be picked up at compile-time.

How do I fix this?

---

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Predictions {
    mapping (address => PredictionCollection) predictions;

    struct PredictionCollection {
        Prediction[] predictions;
        uint length;
    }

    struct Prediction {
        bytes32[8] text;
    }

    struct PredictionInfo {
        bytes32[8] text;
    }

    function open(PredictionInfo calldata prediction) public returns (uint) {
        uint id = predictions[msg.sender].length;
        predictions[msg.sender].predictions[id] = Prediction({
            text: prediction.text
        });
        return id;
    }
}
```

[Here is a link to the deployed contract](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xd14bc40e232b90eaaf168c738ef06c9869c65986).

---

Here is the code for my failed transaction (using [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/)), in case this helps determine why my transaction has failed:

```
async function submitTransaction() {
    let text = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        text.push(web3.utils.asciiToHex("Hello, World! :)\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"));
    }

    await predictionsContract.methods.open({
        text,
    }).send({
        from: wallet,
    });
}
```

[Here is a link to the mined transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xdcccbae489c2e6f81c532bf549a6c376402c12ec4aa7f4e3b2d5eb77dc430dac) which includes the relevant input data.

Edit: This is the raw input data:

```
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
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was accessing an array with index out of bounds. I was modifying the last index rather than pushing an element to the array. (I thought the behaviour of an array was similar to that of a mapping).

**Fixed code**:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Predictions {
    struct PredictionInfo {
        bytes32[8] text;
    }
    
    struct Prediction {
        bytes32[8] text;
    }
    
    mapping (address => Prediction[]) predictions;

    function open(PredictionInfo calldata prediction) public returns (uint) {
        uint id = predictions[msg.sender].length;
        
        predictions[msg.sender].push(Prediction({
            text: prediction.text
        }));
        
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things I noticed that may be causing you trouble:

1. Calldata is only available for external functions. Also, you’ve defined the struct as a storage variable. Why use calldata? Do you mean storage?
2. Need to define the PredictionCollection struct before the mapping using PredictionCollection struct.
3. You have shadow declarations where the mapping is predictions and the first dynamic array in your struct PredictionCollection is also named predictions.

Do you have specs for what you intend the smart contract to do?

Suggestion:

1. Use [Hardhat](https://www.hardhat.org/) console.log to debug.

Comment: Thanks for these possibilities. I will take a look. I intend for the smart contract to simply store the text data (bytes32[8]) into an array inside a mapping, nothing complicated.

Comment: 1. I am surprised there was no compile-time error if this is the case. I will try to change this to memory. 2. I will try this, but once again I would have expected a compile-time error. 3. I don't see why that is a problem.

Comment: I have tried 1 and 2, getting the same error.

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting exactly?

Comment: I tried running it through remix. Coming up with a potentially infinite loop with the gas limit being met running open. No compilation errors. Also, 3. matters for readability and convention. 

`Gas requirement of function Predictions.open is infinite:
If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed.
Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage
(this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)
Pos: 21:4:`

What's a sample input for the `open` function?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I cannot find out how to get an exact error, all I know is that  a revert was triggered. The sample input is that which I generate in the `submitTransaction` function I included in my question. I will see if I can get the exact raw input data corresponding to this transaction. How did you find out about this gas problem? Edit: I have added raw input data to the question.

Comment: I think the error is because array access was out of bounds. I was accessing index directly rather than pushing new element onto array. :facepalm:

Comment: I was manually keeping track of a length variable, thinking that the array behaved like a mapping. Looking back at it now, I really don't know how I made such a silly mistake.

Comment: Used remix.ethereum.org plugin to scan the contract. Have you looked into Hardhat?

Comment: And, for the record, everyone makes mistakes. No harm, no foul. :) Glad you discovered what you needed!

Comment: Haha and thanks for your help anyway. No I haven't looked into hardhat yet since I'm still just developing online, I'll definitely look at it soon.